# Backand: Object exists but not able to access it

Tags: backand

I'm using Backand for my backend service where I have an object that exists in my model diagram but I can't access it. Whenever I try, I get an error that the table doesn't exist. I can't delete it. I've tried renaming it but it only took a single additional character to the name. I've tried to edit it and remove it in the model json area but to know avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you click on save button in bottom of model page?

Comment: Yes, I did and was always getting an error to contact my administrator because "BackandXXXXXXXXX.tablename" did not exist. I couldn't delete it or do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this corrected. My problem came about that at some moment, I went to the Object's Settings tab.  There are two "Names" at the top of that. "Name" and "Database Name". At some point I had changed the "Name" (which is editable) which cause the "Name" and "Database Name" to be different which caused queries to have problems.

So to correct this issue - I renamed the "Name" to be exactly what the "Database Name" is (having to do so slowly as it has an event trigger each time you make a change so it has to wait for the confirmation of each save before typing the next letter). Once I got the "Name" and "Database Name" to match exactly, then I was able to refresh the Object Model and delete out the object.  Then created the Object with the name I really wanted.